# wamp server mysql database don't accept Chinese characters

Tags: mysql, wamp, joomla-community-builder

My Joomla3.0 works fine with Chinese characters on my wamp2.2 server until I installed extension Community builder, every Chinese Characters I input in this extension turned out to be question marks. Upon inspecting databases, I found out that tables created by Community Builder weren't using utf-8 charset, so I alter charsets of those tables to utf8_general_ci, as seen below.
[image] And according to some other posts in stackoverflow.com, I even modified my.ini file so it looks like

```
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
default-character-set=utf8
# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
basedir=d:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24
log-error=d:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=d:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/data


skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
binlog_format=mixed

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1


[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
default-character-set=utf8
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
port=3306
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

However, Chinese characters are still being converted to question marks, and when I tried to directly set the values of those tables to Chinese characters in phpmyadmin, it returned an error message saying "#1366 Incorrect string value". Now with very limited knowledge of mysql database, I am stranded.
Any help is greatly appreicated!

Comment: Your tables must have utf-8 fields too.

Comment: I don't quite get what you said sir. Don't my tables have utf-8 fields after I have set the whole table to utf-8 charset, as seen in the picture in my main thread? If no, where do I check it and set it?

Comment: This problem only happens with my local wamp server, I clone my site to my webspace at hostmonster, and add some fields to community builder, and this time the Chinese characters can be properly displayed. Then I clone the site back to my local server, and now the Chinese charcters can also be seen on local. Hope this piece of infomation can help to address the problem.

Comment: May be you need to install Chinese character-sets/language on your Windows. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-home-premium-my-computer-cant-read/5d8f1220-6f5d-48c3-91f5-65c8334e6abe